# Can we call an asynchronus NSURLRequest from a thread(NSThread)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsthread, nsurlrequest

Is it possible to call an asynchronus NSURLRequest from a thread(NSThread)? 
If yes, then is this a good practice?
If no, then can any one can explain with code snippet that what can be the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but usually not necessary. To do this, you would need to set up an `NSRunLoop` on your secondary thread.

Usually it's better to just use `NSURLConnection` from the main thread, it will still not block. For processing the downloaded data, you could easily use `dispatch_async` from the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` delegate method.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please tell briefly that why I need to set up the NSRunLoop and how can I do that? A code snippet will be helpful to understand that.

Comment: You can find an example in the [XMLPerformance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/XMLPerformance/Listings/Classes_LibXMLParser_m.html) sample code from Apple (look for the `downloadAndParse:` method).

Comment: Thanks. While looking at downloadAndParse:, I am feeling so technical.:)